# How to log in to Wordpress admin dashboard?

Tags: c#, .net, wordpress, cookies

I'm trying to log in to Wordpress admin dashboard using C#.

```
public bool LogIn()
    {
        // webHelper is WebClient with cookies support (I can login on other sites with this class, even on Google)
        string siteHtmlSource = webHelper.DownloadStuff(PageUrl + "/wp-login.php");

        siteHtmlSource = webHelper.UploadStuff(PageUrl + "/wp-login.php",
            "log=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(UserName) + "&pwd=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(PassWord) +
            "&rememberme=forever&wp-submit=Log+In&redirect_to=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(PageUrl) +
            "%2Fwp-admin%2F&testcookie=1");

        if (!siteHtmlSource.Contains("Dashboard"))
        {
            loggedIn = false;
            return false;
        }

        loggedIn = true;
        return true;
    }
```

The code is simple and it works on every site, even on Google (with different parameters of course). 
After sending POST I'm getting into Log In page again...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after 6 hours of thinking I wrote code that **WORKS** (I can download admin dashboard page via WebClient (that supports cookies)). It connects via SSL, creates CookieContainer and put it into WebClient ("WebHelper" in my code).

Here's the code: https://couponsgearbest.wordpress.com/2017/01/29/how-to-log-in-to-wordpress-dashboard-using-c-sharp-programming/